# Styling a button navigation

Tags: html, css

Hi guys so i am trying to create a button navigation for my site. I am trying to get it to work for 4 buttons , i want them to be a circle , all different colors and then when the user hovers over it , it will glow. So i got so far:

HTML:

```
<nav id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="model-icon a-color hvr-glow">

    </li>
    <li  class="model-icon b-color hvr-glow">

    </li>
    <li  class="model-icon c-color hvr-glow">

    </li>
    <li  class="model-icon d-color hvr-glow">

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

#main-menu  > ul > li {
    margin: 0 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.a-color {
    background-color: Yellow;
}

.b-color {
    background-color: Red;
}

.c-color {
    background-color: White;
}

.d-color {
    background-color: Green;
}
```

However the problem is , there is no glow effect and they are boxes rather than circles.

In the future then i will be putting the svg images in the middle of it, using this [site](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/sword_107170#term=sword&page=1&position=20)

However for now i just want to get the boxes to turn into circle and then when the user hovers over it, it glows

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `#main-menu  > ul > li:hover {}`
and adjust the shadows [here](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)

and for the circle:

border-radius:50%;

```css
#main-menu  > ul > li {
    margin: 0 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
#main-menu  > ul > li:hover {
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
border-radius:50%;
}

.a-color {
    background-color: Yellow;
}

.b-color {
    background-color: Red;
}

.c-color {
    background-color: White;
}

.d-color {
    background-color: Green;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="model-icon a-color">

    </li>
    <li  class="model-icon b-color">

    </li>
    <li  class="model-icon c-color">

    </li>
    <li  class="model-icon d-color">

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```